# Nodejitsu: Unable to add properties to package description

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejitsu

I just got my nodejitsu beta activation, and I'm trying to write the hello world example from the nodejitsy handbook, but when I run jitsu deploy it throws this:

```
prompt: App name: (myapp)
subdomain: (omarloren1.myapp)
prompt: scripts.start: (server.js)
error:   Unable to add properties to package description

error:   [TypeError: Object function (script) {
        //
        // Support `scripts.start` starting with executable (`node` or `coffee`).
        //
        var split = script.split(' ');
        if (~['node', 'coffee'].indexOf(split[0])) {
          script = split.slice(1).join(' ');
        }

        try {
          fs.statSync(path.join(dir, script));
          return true;
        }
        catch (ex) {
          return false;
        }
      } has no method 'test']
error:   TypeError: Object function (script) {
        //
        // Support `scripts.start` starting with executable (`node` or `coffee`).
        //
        var split = script.split(' ');
        if (~['node', 'coffee'].indexOf(split[0])) {
          script = split.slice(1).join(' ');
        }

        try {
          fs.statSync(path.join(dir, script));
          return true;
        }
        catch (ex) {
          return false;
        }
      } has no method 'test'
error:   Error running command deploy
```

I'm running node v0.8.1 and jitsu v0.9.1

I've no idea what is happening :{

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in jitsu v0.9.1. Try updating to v0.9.3! This should fix the issues you're having here.

If you have more problems, email support@nodejitsu.com and we'll be glad to follow up.

**edit:** You can do this by running `npm install jitsu -g` again.